# Who knows further prime factors of $3^{3^3}+4^{4^4}=3^{27}+4^{256}\ $?

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

The partial prime factorization of $$3^{3^3}+4^{4^4}=3^{27}+4^{256}$$ is $$43\times 691\times C150$$ , where

> C150 = 451243830308033423066470063548138731446820106370692739801553577347348434357807928408503829911718891653149525735754923799473425194761436743056617460491

is a composite $150$-digit number without a small prime factor.

It is very likely that it has no prime factor with less than $30$ digits because the number passes at least $1000$ ECM-$250$K-curves and at least $1200$ ECM-$1$M-curves.

> Can I take advantage of the special form of the number and accelerate the search of further prime factors ?
>
> Does anyone know further prime factors of $3^{27}+4^{256}$ ?

Comment: Have you tried the Alpertron at https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM ?

Comment: *Who knows further prime factors of $3^{3^3}+4^{4^4}$ ?* - God does. (If there are any other questions, which we mere mortals can *actually* answer, let us know). I am also interested, for instance, in the non-trivial factors of $12^{384}\pm1,$ but this site is not appropriate for this type of questions.

Comment: And what is the next Mersenne record prime, after $2^{74,207,281}-1$ ? Also, the factorization of Fermat numbers $F_m$ is studied. It is only know up to $F_{11}$. What are prime factors of $F_{3^3+4^4}$ ?

Comment: It is ridiculous to compare the Mersenne-prime-hunt and the factorization of the huge Fermat numbers to the search for prime factors of a number with a mere of $150$ digits. Such numbers could be factorized within a few days using a quadratic sieve. I will not do that, but I will continue the search with elliptic curves. Why should this site not be the right place to ask such questions ? Would math-overflow be the right place ?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII alpertron only runs under java. Since it has been decided that Java produces dangerous security-gaps, I was not able to run Java online any more. I have downloaded a brand-new update and I tried to add sites to the exception-list for allowed sites, but it did not work. However, my downloaded program yafu is much faster anyway.

Comment: @Peter: Because this is not a programming site. And neither is *Math Overflow*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C150 is the product of the two primes, one with 55 (decimal) digits and one with 96 digits,

$P55=1449299471738053389661827008867152641816024786660724327$

and

$P96=3113530633988882752054263646036326764738143136281825948356832545797877\
39684923341337929165875133$.

I found these factors using the GMP-ECM algorithm incorporated in Sage, with the initial bound B1 set equal to $11\times10^6$.  It took the program just over 5 days on a Linux laptop.

Comment: Here's a +1 from me! You deserve some acknowledgement for putting in the effort to answer this question.