# What are the prime factors of $4^{256}+253\ $?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, elliptic-curves, prime-factorization

I search a composite number near $4^{4^4}$ with a very large smallest prime factor. A candidate is $$4^{4^4}+253=4^{256}+253$$

The number is composite and has $155$ digits, so it is in the range , the quadratic sieve can handle. But the calculation will take several days.

I ran $500$ elliptic curves with $B1=250K$ and $150$ curves with $B1=1M$ and will continue the search with ECM. Everyone reading this is invited to run MPQS.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1627873/who-knows-further-prime-factors-of-333444-3274256?rq=1

Comment: The title looks like a question to me ...

Comment: At 155 digits you should be running the SNFS, not MPQS.